# How to use 'randi' in MATLAB to generate equally probable samples which are either 0 or 1?

Tags: matlab

How can I use **‘randi’** function in MATLAB to generate a signal sequence s(t) which contains 1e6 samples which are either 0 or 1 and are equally probable. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: if you have integers in the range `X` to `Y`, how can you convert them to numbers in the range `X+Z` to `Y+Z`?

Comment: For a binary sequence you can also use "logicals" instead of integer type. `x = rand(n,1) > 0.5; ` would do it.

Comment: The answer is `randi([0, 1], numSamples, 1);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate random integer uniformly distributed between 1 or 2. Then you can shift it to your liking.

X=randi(2,size,1)-1

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I replace size with 1e6 and that would generate equally probable samples between 1 and 2? So, what about 0 and 1?

Comment: Thats what the -1 for (:

Comment: Uhh Shoot missed that completely! I see! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: At first you generate a vector of your size of ones and twos then you shift it

Comment: You could do it much simpler (Directly) by `randi([0, 1], numSamples, 1);`.